# el plugin de facebook y twitter deja de funcionar

Tags: html, angular, facebook, twitter

hola gente de StackOverflow tengo un problema con un desarrollo que estoy haciendo en Angular, en la pagina de inicio debo mostrar las ultimas publicaciones de redes sociales, por lo que use las herramientas de facebook y twitter para sacar el código correspondiente y ponerlo en mi html y todo funciona bien hasta que hago lo siguiente:

cuando estoy en la pagina de inicio me muestra el facebook y twitter sin ningún problema, pero cuando paso de un componente a otro con routerlink y regreso al inicio ya no se muestra ni el facebook ni el twitter.

cabe destacar que el tengo un login y al momento de navegar hacia el inicio tampoco se muestran ninguno de los 2, la única forma de hacerlo es estando en el inicio y presionar f5 pero esto no me sirve ya que necesito unos datos y manejo guards los cuales se pierden al momento de presionar f5

pondré algunas imágenes para que vean lo que pasa:

[cuando estoy en el inicio y doy f5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSnFf.png)

[asi se ve cuando navego entre componente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKHMg.png)

realmente no se que es lo que pasa, si alguien tiene alguna idea me puede ayudar por favor

para inicializarlo en el index.html

```
<!-- script para twitter -->
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!-- fin twitter -->

  <!-- script facebook -->
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0"
    nonce="ArAMumzP"></script>
  <!-- fin facebook -->
```

y en el componente que lo estoy empleando (inicio)

```
<div class="col-3">
      <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline,events"
        data-width="285px" data-height="600" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true"
        data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a
            href="https://www.facebook.com/Unisabaneta.colombia">facebook</a></blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
```

y el de twitter

```
<div class="col-3">
      <div class ="twitter">
      <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="285" data-height="600" data-theme="light"
        href="https://twitter.com/UNISABANETA?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by UNISABANETA</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

esos dos códigos los da la pagina tanto de facebook como de twitter

Comment: Si es necesario el código. Sobre todo como inicializas el plugin

Comment: ya lo edite con el código, gracias por responder

Comment: Como prueba, en vez de poner las etiquetas `script` en el `index.html`, ponlas directamente dentro del los div (como corresponden a cada servicio). Mi teoría es que al destruirse el componente que llama al script se pierde la relación que hay. Es un comportamiento común en angular por aquello de la "encapsulación".

Comment: si saco el script de el index.html no me muestra nada, ni siquiera dándole f5 (lo puse en diferentes div)